# inserting values into nested map using iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert Xmap into Ymap using iterator.

```
typedef map<float, int> Xmap;
typedef map<float, Xmap> Ymap;

Xmap Xcoordinate;
Ymap Ycoordinate;

int Id;
float x;
float y;
char c;

    while (line >> Id >> c >> x >> c >> y)
    {
        Ymap::iterator iy = Ycoordinate.find(y);
        if (iy == Ycoordinate.end())
            Ycoordinate.insert(pair<float, Xmap>(y, Xmap()));
        iy->second.insert(pair<float, int>(x, Id));
    }
```

I have Id, x, y from a textfile. c is there to take care of the comma.

How do I insert x and Id into the nested Xmap using iterator?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you already _did_ insert your point into nested `Xmap` in this line: `iy->second.insert(pair<float, int>(x, Id));`. Note that each `Ymap`'s entry implicitly contains an `Xmap`, so you don't have to define them yourself. `Xmap Xcoordinate;` defines a completely separate independent `Xmap` which has no idea about `Ycoordinate` or `Ymap` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Ymap::iterator iy = Ycoordinate.find(y);
    if (iy == Ycoordinate.end())
        Ycoordinate.insert(pair<float, Xmap>(y, Xmap()));
    iy->second.insert(pair<float, int>(x, Id));
```

If `find()` did not find `y`, and `iy` is the ending iterator value, the first `insert()` inserts a new entry into the first map.

That's fine and dandy, but by the virtue of the fact that a new value gets inserted into the map, that doesn't automatically change `iy` to refer to the newly-inserted value. As such, `iy` is still `end()`, just like the `if` statement determined, and `iy->second` ends up dereferencing the ending iterator value, resulting in undefined behavior.

One way to fix this is to simply set `iy`:

```
    if (iy == Ycoordinate.end())
        iy=Ycoordinate.insert(pair<float, Xmap>(y, Xmap())).first;
```

See the documentation for the map's `insert()` method, specifically the return value, for more information.

But all of this appears to be completely unnecessary, and a bunch of extra work. All that's happening here, from the looks of it, is that an insertion of a default-initialized value into a map, if the key is not present.

Why reinvent the wheel? That's what `operator[]` is for:

```
while (line >> Id >> c >> x >> c >> y)
{
    Ycoordinate[y].insert(pair<float, int>(x, Id));
}
```

Or, even:

```
while (line >> Id >> c >> x >> c >> y)
{
    Ycoordinate[y][x]=Id;
}
```

That's obviously much simpler. But, if you want to learn how to "insert values into a map using iterator", it logically follows that you need to read `std::map::insert`'s documentation, which tells you exactly how it works. If you do that, you should immediately understand that you can still simplify your logic:

```
while (line >> Id >> c >> x >> c >> y)
{
    Ycoordinate.insert(pair<float, Xmap>(y, Xmap())).first
       ->second.insert(pair<float, int>(x, Id));
}
```

This is still, technically, using iterators since that's one of the things that `insert()` returns.